# Custom field type from SPFieldLookup - item values are not appearing in List view

Tags: 2013, list-view, lookup-column, custom-field-types

I have created custom field type with **SPFieldLookup** as a parent class. 
Using my custom field type, I can able to create custom lookup type columns where source columns are of types: **Choice** and **User** field types.

The values for these types of columns are appearing in OOTB New, Edit and Display forms of the list perfectly. After saving these items, these values are not appearing in list views. The column appears totally blank.

**Here, "Choice_AL" column is my custom field type.
Values appearing in OOTB New item form of list:**

[image]

**Values also saved and shown in OOTB Display form of list:**

[image]

**But values are not appearing in List view:**

[image]

I have added same XML and XSL for custom field type as OOTB SharePoint is providing for lookup.

It is working perfectly for the columns which are supported by lookup field but for "choice" and "user" types it creates problems.

How can I show these item values in SharePoint list views?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I am facing same issue. Is there any solutions for the same? Or if anyone have workaround for same it would be appreciate.

Answer (score -2):

Did you created the custom column by code? I tried to create the custom column by using the SharePoint user interface, the selected value(s) will be shown at the list view.

Comment: I have created a "custom column type" to create new columns using that column type in SharePoint lists and libraries.